# Can you plunge a toilet during Chol Ha'moed?

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, bathroom, chol-hamoed, home-house

It's Chol Ha'moed.  Your house has four bathrooms.  You use one of them, and the toilet clogs.  May you plunge it during Chol Ha'moed?

<sub>(I've done some Web searches.  So far, I have found a discussion of repairing toilets during Shabbat, and [during Erev Pesach](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-eruvpeasch.htm), but not during Ḥol Ha'moed.)</sub>

Comment: I'm curious if there's anything permissible on shabbos but forbidden on Chol hamoed...

Comment: @robev Allowing gentile contractors to build your house outside of the techum

Comment: @robev: Good comment! May we please post your comment as a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC it's the text [shmiras shabbos kehilchasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemirat_Shabbat_Kehilchatah) that allows you to use an ordinary plunger — but not a professional-grade one — to plunge a clogged toilet even on shabbos. So you'd certainly be allowed to do so on Chol HaMoed. As for using a professional-grade plunger: I don't have a source.

Comment: How do I know if a plunger is ordinary or professional-grade? Lately I've been using a large [Master Plunger](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089NJ46D3) with a bellows, since that's what I found lying around the basement. Does _Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchatah_ explain the distinction?

Answer (score 2):

I phoned a rabbi — probably one of the top ten rabbis in my city (a North American city of three million people). He's a charedi Ashkenazi rabbi.

He said I can unblock it using a plunger, since it's unskillful work.